# Create grid with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can make make this in flutter with grid

[Flutter Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuFkB.png)

And one important thing how to set height and width same for all items I mean not changeable. landscape and portrait modes showing different size of gridItems

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      crossAxisCount:
          MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
      children: List.generate(coursesList.length, (index) {
        return GridItemWidget(
            course: coursesList.elementAt(index), heroTag: heroTag);
      }),
    );
  }
```

I made Grid but not designed as in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuFkB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this example do what you want?:

```
GridView.count(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
  crossAxisCount:
    MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text('Description'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 45, color: Colors.white,)),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue[500],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text('Description'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 45, color: Colors.white,)),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue[900],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
      ),
    ),Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text('Description'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 45, color: Colors.white,)),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red[900],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
      ),
    ),Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text('Description'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 45, color: Colors.white,)),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green[900],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: No it shows different for portrait and landscape for example put multiple Text() and test it it shows different. In landscape shows bottom overflod whereas in portrait it works perfect. So it should show same height and width for both modes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I've added the screenshots. I have no overflow error in either Portrait or Landscape.

Comment: But size of items are different in modes.it would be appreciated if can make and share [this grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuFkB.png)

Comment: The grid on that image doesn't show if it's in Portrait or Landscape. I can't understand what you want. What do you mean sizes of items are different, they are squares with the same width and height.

Comment: OK. maybe something goes wrong with my app about sizes of grids. In my question asked not about mostly sizes I asked to about **how to create grid same as in image**

Comment: You mean with Squares with rounded rectangles and a lock in the center?

Comment: I've made the changes as you asked. Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you yes of course I will mark.  But you forget adding number to bottom right and how to fit text in only two lines after put three dots like this (English course bla bla ....)

Comment: I'm sure you can do that part. If someone writes all the code for you, it's harder for you to learn. From what you said you already know how to do it. Experiment with the code I've given you and you will get there!

Comment: Yes you are right how about using positioned instead